# xslt 2.0: read in text files via collection()

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a bunch of text files that I'd like to process witth XSLT 2.0.

Here's how I try to read them in:

```
   <xsl:variable name="input" select="collection(iri-to-uri('file:///.?select=*.txt'))" />
```

However, when I do this:

```
    <xsl:message>
    <xsl:sequence select="count($input)"/>
    </xsl:message>
```

It outputs 0. No files are selected.

If I do it like this:

```
   <xsl:variable name="input" select="collection(iri-to-uri('.?select=*.txt'))" />
```

I get the error that collection should return a `node` but is returning an `xs:string`.

What I would like do to is read each file and then iterate over each file and process the text, like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="unparsed-text($input, 'UTF-8')">
<!-- tokenizing, etc. -->
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the XPath 3.0 `uri-collection` function supported in `version="3.0"` stylesheet in Saxon 9.7 (all versions including HE) and 9.6 (commercial versions I think):

```
<xsl:template match="/" name="main">
    <xsl:for-each select="uri-collection('.?select=*.txt')!unparsed-text(.)">
        <xsl:message select="'Parsed:' || . || '&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

`collection` is supposed to return a sequence of nodes while `uri-collection` can access other resources not parsable as XML.

With Altova XMLSpy respectively RaptorXML and XSLT 3.0 you can also use `uri-collection`, it seems the way to access all `.txt` files is a bit different from Saxon and you use `uri-collection('*.txt')` to access all `.txt` files in the directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hadn't seen that HE already supports 3.0. It works now :) Is this the official syntax? With the !unparsed-text(.)? Or what exactly is the function of the ! there? I haven't found anything via google on that.

Comment: `!` is an operator introduced in XPath 3.0 https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-map-operator which allows you to write `uri-collection('.?select=*.txt')!unparsed-text(.)` instead of `for $uri in uri-collection('.?select=*.txt') return unparsed-text($uri)`.

Comment: Generally, Saxon-HE 9.7 supports XPath 3.0 and its function library but not XSLT 3.0; the policy where it makes sense is to support the minimum conformance level of each standard as it becomes a W3C recommendation (though we don't guarantee always doing that in the future). The collection() function has changed to allow any kind of resource (e.g. text, JSON, binary) in 3.0, and Saxon has changed correspondingly in 9.7.